# Openssl Using openssl for DES/3DES giving odd results?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm working on implementing a support lib that includes DES and 3DES functionality. As a validation step I went to use `openssl` to check my results. For a simple test I did this:

```
echo -n "AAAAAAAA" | openssl enc -e -des-ecb -nosalt -pass pass:AABBCCDD | xxd
00000000: 2976 3faf 5e27 7187 5897 c640 c38c cf8b  )v?.^'q.X..@...
```

That is, ECB mod, plaintext `AAAAAAAA`, key `AABBCCDD`, and no salting. But two things strike me as odd here.

(1) With a 64 bit input and 64 bit block size, I am expecting the output to have the same length as input

(2) If I double the input to 128 bits (all A's, twice the block length) I actually get 24 bytes of cipher text

```
$ echo -n "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" | openssl enc -e -des-ecb -nosalt -pass pass:AABBCCDD | xxd
00000000: 2976 3faf 5e27 7187 2976 3faf 5e27 7187  )v?.^'q.)v?.^'q.
00000010: 5897 c640 c38c cf8b                      X..@....
```

When doing that last experiment I noticed that the cipher text does repeat on block size boundaries (see `2976 3faf 5e27 7187` repeating). But when this threshold is reached we get the additional 8 bytes of ciphertext. Namely, using 7 A's gives 8 bytes ciphertext but 8 A's gives us 16. So there seems to be some odd handling of this boundary condition?

And in any case, I checked a few random online DES tools and none of them matched what openssl provided - yet they all matched each other. From those tools I think the proper ciphertext for my first example above is

`54   55  ab  a4  a2  b0  83  38`

Or they're all wrong in the same way. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking `openssl` to use your key as a *password,* which is a string that needs to go through a KDF function before it can be used as an encryption key of the desired length. The `-nosalt` option merely disables the salt input to the KDF, but not the usage of a KDF in general.

(OpenSSL uses an [iterated MD5 algorithm](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html) as its default KDF, though recent versions support the standard PBKDF2 and usually warn you if it's not enabled.)

To use `AABBCCDD` as the literal 64-bit key, it must be specified through `-K`:

```
$ echo -n "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" | openssl enc -e -des-ecb -K 4141424243434444 | hd
00000000  54 55 ab a4 a2 b0 83 38  54 55 ab a4 a2 b0 83 38  |TU.....8TU.....8|
00000010  55 f8 fc 5b 8f 9a 8e 8c                           |U..[....|
00000018
```

Now you have two blocks of ciphertext, plus one block of *padding.* The `openssl enc` tool applies [PKCS#5 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) to make sure it always has a full number of input blocks – e.g. if your input is only 15 bytes, the last piece will be 7 bytes which cannot be encrypted as-is. It cannot be simply zero-padded, because the recipient wouldn't know how many zero-bytes it can safely remove – after all, the input isn't necessarily *text;* it could also be binary data with a certain amount of legitimate zero-bytes at the end.

The specific form of padding used here uses the last byte to indicate how much padding was added, and therefore how much padding to *remove* after decryption. For example, if the last plaintext block was only 6 bytes, it would be padded with `0x02 0x02` (before encryption) so the recipient would know it needs to strip 2 bytes from the decrypted block.

But when the last block of your plaintext *is* already full-size, there's no space left to indicate that fact – you can't have zero-length padding, because the recipient would *still* look at the last byte of the decrypted plaintext and would get confused because the last byte is some arbitrary data. For that reason, a *whole* block of padding is added, consisting of eight `0x08` bytes.

In ECB mode, you could see this by trying to decrypt the padding as data:

```
$ echo "55 f8 fc 5b 8f 9a 8e 8c  55 f8 fc 5b 8f 9a 8e 8c" | unhex \
  | openssl enc -d -des-ecb -K 4141424243434444 \
  | hexdump -C
00000000  08 08 08 08 08 08 08 08                           |........|
00000008
```

Similarly for a shorter input:

```
$ echo -n "AAAAAAAAAAAAA" \
  | openssl enc -e -des-ecb -K 4141424243434444 \
  | hexdump -C
00000000  54 55 ab a4 a2 b0 83 38  07 5b 23 e5 96 4b 2f 95  |TU.....8.[#..K/.|
00000010

$ echo "07 5b 23 e5 96 4b 2f 95  55 f8 fc 5b 8f 9a 8e 8c" | unhex \
  | openssl enc -d -des-ecb -K 4141424243434444 \
  | hexdump -C
00000000  41 41 41 41 41 03 03 03                           |AAAAA...|
00000008
```

If you have a guarantee that the input will always be an exact multiple of the cipher's block size, then you can tell OpenSSL to disable padding using the **`-nopad`** option and get only the 16 bytes of ciphertext:

```
$ echo -n "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" \
  | openssl enc -e -des-ecb -nopad -K 4141424243434444 \
  | hexdump -C
00000000  54 55 ab a4 a2 b0 83 38  54 55 ab a4 a2 b0 83 38  |TU.....8TU.....8|
00000010
```

Note that the type of padding (or lack thereof) must be specified **when decrypting,** too.

Also note that if you encrypt with `-nopad` but the last block isn't full, OpenSSL will simply throw it away and report an error because there's not much else it can do.

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much. Great bits of internals there too.